# DotLiquid Runtime Error Liquid error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: hash, casting, key, liquid

I am just learning DotLiquid but found an issue around using a hash

Options is a hash

```
        Hash h = new Hash();
        h.Add("Value", this.Field.Value);
        h.Add("Label", this.Field.Label);
        h.Add("FieldName", this.Field.FieldName);

        Hash Options = new Hash();
        Options.Add("4", "Option 1");
        Options.Add("5", "Option 2");
        Options.Add("99", "Option 3");
        h.Add("Options", Options);
```

In my template

```
 {% for item in Options -%}
    {{ item[0] }}{{ item[1] }}
 {% endfor -%}
```

The code above is from the https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers page referring to the FOR Loop

> When iterating a hash, item[0] contains the key, and item[1] contains the value:

```
{% for item in hash %}
  {{ item[0] }}: {{ item[1] }}
{% endfor %}
```

But when it is rendered it generates

**Liquid error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.Liquid error**

Not sure what the problem is?

Comment: I decided to flag using the HASH and use a DROP class instead - it was simpler.

Comment: HeyChris, any chance you could share a snippet of that code. I'm running into the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug (became known after you posted your question): https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/issues/126